# Is there a way to provide LDAP access to Google Analytics and Google Tag Manager to user groups?

Tags: google-analytics, ldap, google-tag-manager

Is there a way to provide LDAP access to Google Analytics GA4 and Google Tag Manager to user groups?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Rather, it is about using LDAP with GA and GTM.

Comment: This might be a good question for [sf] but read their help center first, I'm not totally sure it would be on-topic there.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller why questions about Google Cloud Platform services are programming enough for Stackoverflow, but question about LDAP access (there is Cloud Identity service for similar problem) is not?

Comment: Questions about GCP are on-topic if they are programming related.  I would vote to close many questions about GCP as off-topic.